# Where should I use my Fragrant Branch of Yore?

Tags: dark-souls-2

I'm a mage currently at Harvest Valley and after walking around for a bit, I found a Fragrant Branch of Yore. But this is the only one I have with me right now and it seems that I can do some stuff with it:

1. Use it on the petrified lion on Shaded Ruins to get the Fang Key 2
2. Use it on another petrified lion on Shaded Ruins to get the Lion Mage Set
3. Use it on the Straid of Olaphis near Sinner's Rise

Where should I use it? And where should I go from where I am now?

Comment: I've edited your question to correct some grammar and hopefully remaining the original sense. However, I would still say the question is somewhat subjective. Although I don't play the game, the [first](http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/Fragrant+Branch+of+Yore#.U0mkH6JXYVA) [two](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Fragrant_Branch_of_Yore) wiki results I got in Google seem to convey every usage of that item.

Comment: It is important to note that there is actually more branches of yore than there are places to use them in a single playthrough (they get deleted when you enter ng+).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use it to get the Lion Mage set because you get another Fragrant Branch of Yore from it, which you should then use on Straid of Olaphis (in my opinion he has the better items for sale, especially if you use miracles, sorcery or even pyromancy)

In short:
**Lion Mage set (you get another branch) then Straid**

Comment: That's what i did. And gotta say...that casting speed buff is beautiful. Now, off to farm some stones to upgrade my armor. Btw, do you guys know any good weapon/shield for a mage?

Comment: Blue Flame, it has good scaling and can be used a sword and a catalyst http://darksouls2.wikidot.com/blue-flame

Comment: There is a way to get the lion mage set without the use of the branch. Although it is difficult. (i did it in less than 15 minutes on the 60 fps)

Answer (score 5):

I would suggest using it on [Rosabeth of Melfia](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Rosabeth_of_Melfia) as it unlocks a large portion of the game and as a bonus, she sells pyromancy items and can upgrade your pyromancy flame.

She is down a path between Things Betwixt and Majula. Go back out of Majula and hug the wall to the right and eventually you'll go through a short set of ruins and then reach a man sitting down with a bluemoon greatsword (its very recognizable). She's blocking a lever that would allow a door behind her to open to go to Shaded Woods. 
http://darksouls2.wiki.fextralife.com/file/view/DS2map1.jpg 
(map is of the entire game just as a heads up if you're worried about spoiling some information past this)

Comment: I was originally going to suggest this to, but he already has the Shaded Ruins unlocked so he seems to have freed Rosabeth already.

Comment: @PanicBomb well that explains why it wasn't one of the options....  scanned a bit too fast there i guess

Comment: @PanicBomb I initially thought the same thing, but OP states he is in Harvest Valley, which is *not* a prerequisite for the Shaded Woods, nor is it after of Rosabeth of Melfia. I assume he googled the uses of the fragrant branch and does not realize that he will need to use the branch at Rosabeth to gain access to shaded woods, making the only two areas he *can* use the branch Rosabeth or Straid.